# How to inspect the payload of a guzzle request

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, put, guzzle

Guzzle includes a simple NodeJS server for testing, and I am using that to mock my backend. The server contains a `getReceivedRequests` method which returns a list of all the requests that it had received, and I am trying to inspect the requests to make sure my program is sending them correctly.

For `GET` requests it's easy enough. Looking at the `Request` class, I can get the query parameters and assert on them.

The question comes when I am trying to inspect a `PUT` request. Looking at the `Request` class there seems to be no way for me to get its payload. In fact I don't even know where the payload is stored in the object, as there is no private fields indicated as such.

Is there anyway I can assert on the payload of a guzzle request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use that to inspect and debug my request payload

`$request->getBody()->read($request->getBody()->getSize())`

Comment: Thanks @MavenACTG :)